# How to convert nullable DateTime?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

```
string fc = .......
Dictionary<string, string> fcData = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(fc);


if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fcData["Diploma.GraduationBeginDate"]))
  DateTime? GraduationBeginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fcData["Diploma.GraduationBeginDate"]);
```

> Error : {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

This is my code . `fcData` has value, `count =11`   and  `fcData["Diploma.GraduationBeginDate"]` value is `10.05.2016`   why it doesn't work ? Could you help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nope , i couldnt find.

Comment: Please post a more complete section of your code without `.......`. Also - when you debug the code and go line my line on what line does it throw the exception?

Comment: At which line does the exception occur?

Comment: One of your objects doesn't have a value. Debug the code and find which line throws the exception. Then hover your mouse over each object in that statement looking for a `null` value. If `fcData` has a value I suspect you're getting the exception at the `Deserialize` statement? Possibly your `serializer` hasn't been initialized. Without seeing your full code we can only guess. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the linked [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thank you for information . I solved the problem .  "GraduationBeginDate" is actually  "diploma.GraduationBeginDate"  this is my mistake.By the way diploma is object.The problem is Before set , i didn't take instance . thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can affect DateTime to DateTime? :

```
DateTime t1 = someDate;
DateTime? t2;
t2 = t1; <- it works
```

in contrary :

```
DateTime? t1 = someDate;
DateTime t2;
t2 = t1; <- won't work, you need to cast it
t2 = (DateTime)t1;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for information . I solved the problem .  "GraduationBeginDate" is actually  "diploma.GraduationBeginDate"  this is my mistake.By the way diploma is object.The problem is Before set , i didn't take instance . thanks again for your help.